# Trying add mixed geometry types to same drawingTools GeometryLayer, get Error: Geometries parameter must be an array of ee.Geometry or GeoJson objects

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection(mycollection);

var myGeometry = collection.filter(predicates).geometry();

myGeometry.evaluate(function(geomList) {
        // Add the geometry as a layer of the drawing tools.
        drawingTools.addLayer([geomList], 'myGeometryLayer', 'red');
      });
```

> Error: Geometries parameter must be an array of ee.Geometry or GeoJson
>   objects

Error only occurs if myGeometry is of more than one type (in my case, Points and MultiPolygons)

How can I add myGeometry to the drawingTools layer when it is of mixed type please?

Comment: Please include a link to a running code editor script, and make sure all your used assets are shared. That makes it easier to help you.